# Finding the accuracy - Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, model, scikit-learn

I have the following Python code snippet where I'm trying to run SVC on some data (The library used is [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html):

```
(trainFeat, testFeat, trainLabels, testLabels) = train_test_split(
    data, data_labels, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

model = SVC(kernel='poly', max_iter=10,probability=True,class_weight='balanced')
model.fit(np.reshape(trainFeat, (124,-1)), trainLabels)
accuracy = model.score(testFeat, testLabels)
print('Accuracy: {:.2f}%'.format(acc * 100))
```

I'm however having the error below for `accuracy = model.score(testFeat, testLabels)`:

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

What should I do to fix this error?

Thanks.

Comment: you posted that question twice, why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fitting a model - Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593211/fitting-a-model-found-array-with-dim-3-estimator-expected-2)

Comment: @Banana  This question is actually different. The first was related to fitting the model, but this question is regarding finding the "score"

Answer (score 2):

The code worked when I applied cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's suggestion in my other question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593211/fitting-a-model-found-array-with-dim-3-estimator-expected-2):

```
model.score(np.reshape(testFeat, (-1, 9 * 6)), testLabels)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are predicting for 3 classes. And it is giving you 3 dimension array with probability of each class.

Try doing this:

```
model = SVC(kernel='poly', max_iter=10,probability=False,class_weight='balanced')
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to predict 2 classes. I tried your suggestion, but the error remained